# Facebook Comment Box Plugin sends too many Red Alert On Site notifications

Tags: facebook, plugins, notifications, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have recently implemented the Facebook Comments box plugin and have multiple users set as admins via the plugin itself. These users are also admins on our facebook fan page but they are NOT listed in the OG:admin tag. These users receive tons of On-Site (red alert) notifications whenever a comment is left via the comment box and we would like to turn that off.

I have also tried having users set via OG:admin and NOT through the app itself and while that seems to stop the notifications, it also disables the ability to moderate all the comments via http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ note: these OG:admins can moderate comments on the individual stories, just not all in the above moderation tool.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I think I've found the solution.

1- Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

2- Click on "Settings" (top right). A popup will appear.

3- On the first tab, 3rd option, set "Ensable notifications" to "Off" (as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bUBD.png)

---

By the way, I've found a similar question and I've also posted my answer here: [How to disable Facebook "commented on your site" notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085175/how-to-disable-facebook-commented-on-your-site-notification/39191646#39191646). I'm new to Stack Overflow. I hope this is correct.