# How to disable Facebook "commented on your site" notification

Tags: facebook

Within the last week, Facebook began pushing notices to me whenever someone posts a comment to a site that I'm an admin on. It's irritating and something I don't need to see. Any way for me to disable this?

I am referring to the Facebook Comments Plugin, not comments on a Facebook page.

Additional odd part I've noticed, the notifications I'm getting seem to be from Facebook users I've banned from commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Any settings regarding what you are asking about can be found in:
Settings > Notifications > Pages you manage

Comment: I don't think that's the correct setting as it's already disabled for the page in question and I'm not talking about page comments. I'm talking about Facebook comments that appear on websites using the comments pulgin.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to moderate comments, you can delete yourself from `Moderators` group. Just go to [Comment Moderation Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/), choose your app, click `Settings`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I do need to moderate comments, I just don't need a notification every single time someone leaves one. With about a hundred comments a day, it get's pretty irritating.

Comment: Yes, my situation was similar. Just try to do actions from my answer, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I think I've found the solution.

1- Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

2- Click on "Settings" (top right). A popup will appear.

3- On the first tab, 3rd option, set "Enable notifications" to "Off" (as shown here:)[image]